# using jQuery for iPhone webapp, 'on' doesn't work for dynamically created elements

Tags: jquery, iphone, events, dynamic, element

The following code adds <div3> to the html when <div1> is clicked. Clicking <div3> then shows the alert on every webbrowser tested EXCEPT iPhone. Works on Android, works on Safari/OSX:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#div1').on('click', function(e) { 
        $('#div2').html('<div id="div3">Now Click Me!</div>'); 
    });
    $('#div2').on('click', '#div3', function(e) { alert('OLA!'); }); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='div1' style='border:black 1px solid; background:yellow'>CLICK ME</div>
<div id='div2'  style='border:black 1px solid; background:yellow; font-size:48px'/>
</body>
</html>
```

I am hoping to find out why the Safari/iPhone behaves differently here, and whether there is a way to work around this behaviour.

Comment: very interesting... I created a JS Fiddle for this http://tiny.cc/iphonetest1 (minorly modified for jsfiddle, and you're right it doesn't work on the iphone/safari)

Comment: it also doesn't work in Google Chrome for iOS... so this might be a mobile WebKit issue, not just a mobile Safari issue

Comment: Yes, and we're dead in the water on this app if we can't pick up clicks on dynamically created elements.

Comment: File a bug with Jquery, Google and/or Apple?

Comment: Hmm, after further testing... other mobile webkit versions are OK. the code works the PlayBook, BB10 Dev Alpha, and Samsung Galaxy S3 just fine (all running versions of WebKit)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the issue. The click is not registering in div3 because div3 is transparent. Adding a background color to div3 works:

```
$('#div2').html('<div id="div3" style="background:pink;">Now Click Me!</div>');
```

Thanks for the help.